# Can't force function table to specific address with IAR ARM compiler

Tags: c, linker, arm, cortex-m, iar

I have a function table type defined like so

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t majorRevision;
    uint16_t minorRevision;
    uint8_t  (*CommInit)(void *);
    uint8_t  (*CommDeInit)(void);
    uint16_t (*Write)(uint8_t *, uint16_t);
    uint16_t (*Read)(uint8_t *, uint16_t);
    uint8_t  (*Attached)(void);
    uint8_t  (*ExitApp)(uint8_t);
    uint8_t  (*Jump)(uint32_t address);
    uint16_t (*GetCRC)(uint8_t*, uint32_t);
    int      (*Encrypt)(uint8_t *, uint32_t);
    int      (*Decrypt)(uint8_t *, uint32_t);
    uint8_t  (*Reset)(void);
    uint32_t (*GetTickCount)(void);
    void     (*Sleep)(uint32_t);
    uint8_t  (*ReadASCIIByte)(void);
    uint16_t (*ReadASCIIWord)(void);
    uint32_t (*ReadASCIIDWord)(void);
    void     (*WriteASCIIByte)(uint8_t);
    void     (*WriteASCIIWord)(uint16_t);
    void     (*WriteASCIIDWord)(uint32_t);
    void     (*PutChar)(uint8_t);
    uint8_t  (*GetChar)(void);
    uint8_t  (*WaitChar)(uint8_t *, uint32_t);
    uint8_t  (*IsOpen)(void);
} BootFunctionTable_t;
```

Then I declare a variable of that type using the default_function_attribute pragma to force it to a specific address and fill it with my specific functions.

```
#pragma default_variable_attributes = @ "boottable"
BootFunctionTable_t bootFunctions =
{
        MAJOR_REVISION,
        MINOR_REVISION,
        BootSerialInit,     /* Communication Init */
        BootSerialDeInit,   /* Communication Deinit */
        BootSerialWrite,
        BootSerialRead,
        BootSerialAttached,
        BootExitToApp,
        BootJump,
        BootGetCRC,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        BootReset,
        BootGetTickCount,
        BootSleep,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        BootSerialPutChar,
        BootSerialGetChar,
        NULL
};
#pragma default_variable_attributes =
```

In main I create a new pointer and point it to the address of where I attempted to force this table

```
BootFunctionTable_t * bootf;
bootf = (BootFunctionTable_t *)0x080000200;
```

Finally, I create the section in my linker file

```
/*###ICF### Section handled by ICF editor, don't touch! ****/
/*-Editor annotation file-*/
/* IcfEditorFile="$TOOLKIT_DIR$\config\ide\IcfEditor\cortex_v1_0.xml" */
/*-Specials-*/

define symbol __ICFEDIT_intvec_start__ =    0x08000000;

/*-Memory Regions-*/
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_ROM_start__    = 0x08000300;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_ROM_end__      = 0x080FFFFF;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_RAM_start__    = 0x20000000;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_RAM_end__      = 0x2001FFFF;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_CCMRAM_start__ = 0x10000000;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_CCMRAM_end__   = 0x1000FFFF;
/*-Sizes-*/
define symbol __ICFEDIT_size_cstack__ = 0x400;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_size_heap__   = 0x200;
/**** End of ICF editor section. ###ICF###*/


define memory mem with size = 4G;
define region ROM_region        = mem:[from __ICFEDIT_region_ROM_start__   to __ICFEDIT_region_ROM_end__];
define region RAM_region        = mem:[from __ICFEDIT_region_RAM_start__   to __ICFEDIT_region_RAM_end__];
define region CCMRAM_region     = mem:[from __ICFEDIT_region_CCMRAM_start__   to __ICFEDIT_region_CCMRAM_end__];
define region BOOTTABLE_region  = mem:[from 0x08000200 to 0x080002FF];

initialize by copy {section boottable};
place in BOOTTABLE_region { readonly section boottable};

define block CSTACK    with alignment = 8, size = __ICFEDIT_size_cstack__   { };
define block HEAP      with alignment = 8, size = __ICFEDIT_size_heap__     { };

initialize by copy { readwrite };
do not initialize  { section .noinit };

place at address mem:__ICFEDIT_intvec_start__ { readonly section .intvec };


place in ROM_region   { readonly };
place in RAM_region   { readwrite,
                        block CSTACK, block HEAP };
```

But I can't the linker to place bootFunctions at the requested address. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I can't even get the section to show up in the map file. The only example I can find of this is the .intvec section but the vector table is defined in an assembly file. I would like to place my boottable in a C file.

Comment: I guess `#pragma default_variable_attributes = @ "boottable"` creates the section for you. You need to place the section into a region. If your code compiles correctly you should see the symbol in the map, but placed to a default section.

Comment: I create the section in the linker script as posted above.  default_variable_attributes just placed in the section I have already created.

Comment: `from 0x08000200 to 0x000002FF` is not a valid range.

Comment: Thanks @ElderBug, unfortunately that doesn't fix it though. I had it right at one time but I screwed it up when I started moving it around trying to see if I was trying to stick it in a forbidden location. I've edited the original post to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols that are not used are excluded by the linker.

Try to explicitly tell linker to keep the section. Add a line like:

```
keep { section boottable };
```

Answer (score 0):

@user694733 is correct. Because I wasn't actually using

```
BootFunctionTable_t bootFunctions
```

but rather the hardcoded address the linker was leaving it out. I changed the code to

```
BootFunctionTable_t * bootf;
bootf = &bootFunctions;
```

and that also fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I couldn't get the 'keep' linker instruction to work for me. What I did find was the IAR note 51348 https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/linker/the-linker-removing-functions-and-variables-or-external-not-found/ which suggests using __root to force the linker to keep stuff, and that worked for me.